# Process in rc.local does not seem to run -- where to see?

Tags: ubuntu, startup-scripts, rc.local

I want to run a process in `rc.local` (Ubuntu Natty) but I am having trouble determining if it has run.  I added

```
/bin/sleep 10
/usr/bin/killall PassengerWatchdog
/bin/echo "Killall returned with code $?"
```

The file has the execute bit set.  The script starts with `#!/bin/sh`   I would expect the echo to go to `/var/log/boot.log`

This is obviously just a hack to see if I can fix a problem. How can I tell if the script executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect the output of your script to a file in rc.local e.g.

```
/path/to/yourscript >/tmp/script.out 2>&1
```

which should capture the stdout and stderr from yourscript.

Answer (score 2):

In order to log all the output to a file, i.e., add the following to all your commands in rc.local:

```
>> /var/log/rc.local.log 2>&1
```

This will collect both stdout and stderr to /var/log/rc.local.log

then you should be able to know what happened.